# How to navigate Disassembly view to specific absolute address location?

Tags: x64dbg

I have an absolute address that I want to scroll the Disassembly to in order to see which instructions are at that address. I understand that I can scroll by hand, or I can edit RIP. But the former may be slow and the latter is intrusive, I don't want to edit the state of the process. Is there a command for this?

I've found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, but this is "Go to offset", it doesn't accept absolute addresses.

Comment: Are you trying to go to a VA? Then CTRL+G is what you are looking for.

Comment: @LucaD'Amico: yes, this does work, thank you! Please post an answer. But what is VA? Virtual address?

Comment: I'm converting my comment to an answer, and I'll explain also what a VA is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **x64dbg**, you can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to quickly move to a VA.

A VA is a Virtual Address and an RVA is a Relative Virtual Address (the relative address with respect to the imagebase).